# Expanding collections with EntitySetController in MVC Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm using the OData framework (version 5.0.0) together with MVC Web Api (MVC version 4.0.305060), and cannot get the $expand query to work for my collections.

According to [this wiki page](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24select%20and%20%24expand%20support), and more specifically case #2 under "Supported scenarios", I should be able to expand on Collections to include their data in a single query, but my $expand query seems to be completely ignored. No error, the response is exactly the same as if I left out the $expand altogether.

This is (part of) my data structure:

```
DebtCalculation
    - string Name
    - string Description
    - Collection<Expense> Expenses
    - Collection<Participant> Participants

Participant
    - bool HasPaid
    - User User
    - DebtCalculation DebtCalculation

Expense
    - decimal Amount
    - User Payer
    - Collection<Debtor> Debtors
    - DebtCalculation DebtCalculation
```

To summarize; querying with $expand for a single entity works as expected, both through `myservice/api/Expenses?$expand=Payer` and `myservice/api/Expenses(10)?$expand=Payer`, but querying for `myservice/api/DebtCalculations?$expand=Participants` does not.

This is (part of) my controller and ODataConventionModelBuilder setup:

```
[Authorize]
public class DebtCalculationsController : EntitySetController<DebtCalculation, long>
{
    private DebtCalculationManager _debtCalculationManager { get; set; }

    public DebtCalculationsController(DebtCalculationManager debtCalculationManager)
    {
        _debtCalculationManager = debtCalculationManager;
    }

    public override IQueryable<DebtCalculation> Get()
    {
        return _debtCalculationManager.AllDebtCalculationsForApi();
    }

    protected override DebtCalculation GetEntityByKey(long key)
    {
        return _debtCalculationManager.GetDebtCalculation(key);
    }

    public IQueryable<Participant> GetParticipants(long key)
    {
        return _debtCalculationManager.GetDebtCalculation(key).Participants.AsQueryable();
    }

    public IQueryable<Expense> GetExpenses(long key)
    {
        return _debtCalculationManager.GetDebtCalculation(key).Expenses.AsQueryable();
    }
}

[Authorize]
public class ExpensesController : EntitySetController<Expense, long>
{
    private DebtCalculationManager _debtCalculationManager { get; set; }

    public ExpensesController(DebtCalculationManager debtCalculationManager)
    {
        _debtCalculationManager = debtCalculationManager;
    }

    public override IQueryable<Expense> Get()
    {
        return _debtCalculationManager.AllDebtCalculationsForApi()
            .SelectMany(dc => dc.Expenses);
    }

    protected override Expense GetEntityByKey(long key)
    {
        return _debtCalculationManager.ExpenseForApi(key);
    }

    public User GetPayer(long key)
    {
        return _debtCalculationManager.ExpenseForApi(key).Payer;
    }

    public IQueryable<Debtor> GetDebtors(long key)
    {
        return _debtCalculationManager.ExpenseForApi(key).Debtors.AsQueryable();
    }

    public DebtCalculation GetDebtCalculation(long key)
    {
        return _debtCalculationManager.ExpenseForApi(key).DebtCalculation;
    }
}

[Authorize]
public class ParticipantsController : EntitySetController<Participant, long>
{
    private DebtCalculationManager _debtCalculationManager { get; set; }

    public ParticipantsController(DebtCalculationManager debtCalculationManager)
    {
        _debtCalculationManager = debtCalculationManager;
    }

    public override IQueryable<Participant> Get()
    {
        return _debtCalculationManager.AllDebtCalculationsForApi()
            .SelectMany(dc => dc.Participants);
    }

    protected override Participant GetEntityByKey(long key)
    {
        return _debtCalculationManager.ParticipantForApi(key);
    }

    public DebtCalculation GetDebtCalculation(long key)
    {
        return _debtCalculationManager.ParticipantForApi(key).DebtCalculation;
    }
}

public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static HttpConfiguration Config { get; set; }

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        modelBuilder.EntitySet<DebtCalculation>("DebtCalculations")
            .EntityType.HasKey(dc => dc.Id);

        modelBuilder.EntitySet<Participant>("Participants")
            .EntityType.HasKey(p => p.Id)
            .Ignore(p => p.UniqueKey);

        modelBuilder.EntitySet<Expense>("Expenses")
            .EntityType.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        ...

        var model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();

        var routingConventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();
        routingConventions.Insert(0, new CreateNavigationPropertyRoutingConvention());

        config.Routes.MapODataRoute("ODataRoute", "api", model, new DefaultODataPathHandler(), routingConventions);

        config.EnableQuerySupport();
    }

    // routing convention to handle POST requests to navigation properties.
    public class CreateNavigationPropertyRoutingConvention : EntitySetRoutingConvention
    {
        public override string SelectAction(ODataPath odataPath, HttpControllerContext controllerContext, ILookup<string, HttpActionDescriptor> actionMap)
        {
            if (odataPath.PathTemplate == "~/entityset/key/navigation" && controllerContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Post)
            {
                IEdmNavigationProperty navigationProperty = (odataPath.Segments[2] as NavigationPathSegment).NavigationProperty;
                controllerContext.RouteData.Values["key"] = (odataPath.Segments[1] as KeyValuePathSegment).Value; // set the key for model binding.
                return "PostTo" + navigationProperty.Name;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

The metadata for `DebtCalculation` looks like this:

```
    <EntityType Name="DebtCalculation">
            <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
            </Key>
            <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false"/>
            <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String"/>
            <Property Name="Description" Type="Edm.String"/>
            <NavigationProperty Name="Participants" Relationship="Sujut.Core.Sujut_Core_DebtCalculation_Participants_Sujut_Core_Participant_ParticipantsPartner" ToRole="Participants" FromRole="ParticipantsPartner"/>
            <NavigationProperty Name="Expenses" Relationship="Sujut.Core.Sujut_Core_DebtCalculation_Expenses_Sujut_Core_Expense_ExpensesPartner" ToRole="Expenses" FromRole="ExpensesPartner"/>
    </EntityType>
```

Recognize any problems?

Edit:

The problem seems to be combining ODataController querying with Linq-to-NHibernate. Here is the stack trace. An upgrade to the NH 4.0.0.1000 alpha release did not solve the problem. [This bug report](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3556) seems to be about the same issue.

```
System.ArgumentException
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Condition(Expression test, Expression ifTrue, Expression ifFalse)
 at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitConditionalExpression(ConditionalExpression expression)
 at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
 at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.NhExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
 at NHibernate.Linq.NestedSelects.SelectClauseRewriter.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
 at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitBinaryExpression(BinaryExpression expression)
 at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
 at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.NhExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
 at NHibernate.Linq.NestedSelects.SelectClauseRewriter.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
 at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitConditionalExpression(ConditionalExpression expression)
 at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
 at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.NhExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
 at NHibernate.Linq.NestedSelects.SelectClauseRewriter.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
 at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment memberAssigment)
 at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding memberBinding)
 at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitList[T](ReadOnlyCollection`1 list, Func`2 visitMethod)
 at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMemberBindingList(ReadOnlyCollection`1 expressions)
 at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMemberInitExpression(MemberInitExpression expression)
 at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
 at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.NhExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
 at NHibernate.Linq.NestedSelects.SelectClauseRewriter.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
 at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment memberAssigment)
 at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding memberBinding)
 at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitList[T](ReadOnlyCollection`1 list, Func`2 visitMethod)
 at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMemberBindingList(ReadOnlyCollection`1 expressions)
 at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMemberInitExpression(MemberInitExpression expression)
 at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
 at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.NhExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
 at NHibernate.Linq.NestedSelects.SelectClauseRewriter.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
 at NHibernate.Linq.NestedSelects.NestedSelectRewriter.ReWrite(QueryModel queryModel, ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
 at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root)
 at NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression.Translate(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory)
 at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryIdentifier, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
 at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
 at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
 at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
 at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
 at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
 at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
 at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)
 at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
 at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
 at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
 at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataFeedSerializer.WriteFeed(IEnumerable enumerable, IEdmTypeReference feedType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
 at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataFeedSerializer.WriteObjectInline(Object graph, IEdmTypeReference expectedType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
 at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataFeedSerializer.WriteObject(Object graph, Type type, ODataMessageWriter messageWriter, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
 at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders)
 at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
 at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Does the metadata for DebtCollection have the NavigationProperty for Participants?

Comment: Added the metadata for DebtCalculation to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with Linq-to-NHibernate, bug reported [here](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3556).

Worked around the problem by calling `.ToList().AsQueryable()` on the returned `IQueryable<DebtCalculation>` set. This is obviously not very efficient, but will allow me to continue development and testing of apps relying on the API until bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and I tried the workaround, but for big datasets, it seemed to trigger a lot of select statements due to lazy loading.

So I took a different approach and manually joined on the related tables.

```
  // Using Chinook Database
  Album albumAlias = null;
  Track trackAlias = null;
  Artist artistAlias = null;
  return session.QueryOver<Album>(() => albumAlias)
    .Left.JoinAlias(() => albumAlias.Tracks, () => trackAlias)
    .Left.JoinAlias(() => albumAlias.Artist, () => artistAlias)
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
    .List().AsQueryable();
```

Album has many Tracks and a single Artist associated with it.
This way it will only generate a single select statement, and will still be able to expand on either properties.

For your example it will probably look something like

```
DebtCalculation debtCalculationAlias = null;
Expense expenseAlias = null;
Participant participantAlias = null;
session.QueryOver<DebtCalculation>(() => debtCalculationAlias)
.Left.JoinAlias(() => debtCalculationAlias.Expenses, () => expenseAlias)
.Left.JoinAlias(() => debtCalculationAlias.Participants, () => participantAlias)
.TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
.List().AsQueryable();
```

I'm just getting into OData, so if you think this is not the right way to go, feel free to correct me.