# Aren't Collection or arrays used in Web API odata models?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

My experiment [Expanding collections using Web Api OData controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998867/expanding-collections-using-web-api-odata-controller) triggered me to think about my design.

I am wondering am I the only one using collection in a web api model because I dont find many examples, etc on any forums of such kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this sample http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataQueryLimitationsSample/ . It uses collections: Customer.Orders.

Comment: Thanks. Read a bit more about collection types in edm. They seem standard.